# Java object serialization issue while reading object

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, integer

I had serialized several `Data` and `java.lang.Integer`  objects but while reading Data object using stream `Data` objects value are not correctly read while in case of `java.lang.Integer` objects values read are correct.

Data.java

```
public class Data implements Serializable{
    private Integer count ;
    public void setCount(Integer count ) {
        this.count = count;
        }
    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

SerializationTest.java

```
public class SerializationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oosD = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        ObjectInputStream oisD = null;
        try{
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("integer1.dat"),false));
            oosD = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("Data1.dat"),false));
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setCount(10);
            oos.writeObject(new Integer(10));
            oosD.writeObject(data);

            data.setCount(100);
            oos.writeObject(new Integer(100));
            oosD.writeObject(data);

            data.setCount(1000);
            oos.writeObject(new Integer(1000));
            oosD.writeObject(data);
            oos.close();
            oosD.close();

            ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("integer1.dat")));
            System.out.println("Integer output");
            System.out.println("First Object : "+ (Integer)ois.readObject());           
            System.out.println("Second Object : "+ (Integer)ois.readObject());  
            System.out.println("Third Object : "+ (Integer)ois.readObject());
            ois.close();
            System.out.println("Data output");
            oisD = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("Data1.dat")));
            System.out.println("First Object : "+ ((Data)oisD.readObject()).getCount());            
            System.out.println("Second Object : "+ ((Data)oisD.readObject()).getCount());   
            System.out.println("Third Object : "+ ((Data)oisD.readObject()).getCount());
            oisD.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){ ioe.printStackTrace();  }
        catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();    }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Integer output
First Object : 10
Second Object : 100
Third Object : 1000
Data output
First Object : 10
Second Object : 10
Third Object : 10
```

Can anybody help me to figure out the issue with `Data` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are serializing the same Data instance each time.  java serialization stores references to objects and just references the previous storage when you attempt to store the same instance multiple times (this solves circular reference issues).  Create a new Data instance each time.

Comment: As I am changing value of DATA value then It should store last value not first the value of the object.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya - i did correct your understanding, which part of my answer don't you understand?

Comment: as Integer is immutable classe if I changes the value of those integer then their references will be different so I that case it should point to current value of Integer object and as reference is changed then it should store new value.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya - i understand what you _think_ should happen, however i'm telling you what _actually_ happens.  Because you are storing the same _Data_ instance, the new count Integer never gets stored.

Comment: Thanks for guideline to resolve the issue. After your suggestion I had did some changes in code (Without creating new instance of DATA each time) . Reset ObjectOutputStream and it had resolved the problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()

Comment: @AlpeshGediya - yes, using reset will work as well (also probably `writeUnshapred()`).  is there a reason you didn't want to create a new Data instance?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        Data data = null;
        data = new Data();
        data.setCount(10);
        oos.writeObject(new Integer(10));
        oosD.writeObject(data);

        data = new Data();
        data.setCount(100);
        oos.writeObject(new Integer(100));
        oosD.writeObject(data);

        data = new Data();
        data.setCount(1000);
        oos.writeObject(new Integer(1000));
        oosD.writeObject(data);
        oos.close();
        oosD.close();
```